# AGM Series Hole 1: Calculate the Arithmetic–Geometric Mean

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

*This question was inspired by [this HNQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566017/what-happens-if-you-repeatedly-take-the-arithmetic-mean-and-geometric-mean/1566049#1566049).*

### About the series

This question is now part of a series about the AGM method. This first post in the series will be about actually calculating the `AGM`. You may treat this like any other code golf challenge, and answer it without worrying about the series at all. However, there is a leaderboard across all challenges.

### What is the Arithmetic–Geometric Mean

The [Arithmetic–Geometric Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) of two numbers is defined as the number that repeatedly taking the arithmetic and geometric means converges to. Your task is to find this number after some `n` iterations.

### Clarifications

- You take three numbers, `a, b, n` in any reasonable format.
- For `n` iterations, take the arithmetic and geometric mean of `a` and `b` and set those to `a` and `b`.
- For two numbers `a` and `b`, the arithmetic mean is defined as `(a + b) / 2`.
- The geometric mean is defined as `√(a * b)`.
- `a` and `b` should be approaching each other.
- Then, output both `a` and `b`.
- You don't have to worry about float imprecision and such.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

### Test Cases

```
[0, [24, 6]] -> [24, 6]    
[1, [24, 6]] -> [15.0, 12.0]
[2, [24, 6]] -> [13.5, 13.416407864998739]
[5, [24, 6]] -> [13.458171481725616, 13.458171481725616]
[10, [100, 50]] -> [72.83955155234534, 72.83955155234534]

The next one is 1/Gauss's Constant:
[10, [1, 1.41421356237]] -> [1.198140234734168, 1.1981402347341683]
```

### Leaderboard

*Stolen from Martin's series.*

The following snippet will generate a leaderboard across all challenges of the series.

To make sure that your answers show up, please start every answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where N is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you can keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_IDs = [66068]; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!.FjwQBrX2KXuFkv6p2lChi_RjzM19";

/* App */

var answers = [], page = 1, currentQ = -1;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_IDs.join(";") + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}


function getAnswers() {
  $.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      if (data.has_more) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers();

var SIZE_REG = /\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;((?!&gt;).)*&lt;\/s&gt;|((?!&gt;).)+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;
var NUMBER_REG = /\d+/;
var LANGUAGE_REG = /^#*\s*([^\n,]+)(?=,)/;//

function shouldHaveHeading(a) {
  var pass = false;
  var lines = a.body_markdown.split("\n");
  try {
    pass |= /^#/.test(a.body_markdown);
    pass |= ["-", "="]
              .indexOf(lines[1][0]) > -1;
    pass &= LANGUAGE_REG.test(a.body_markdown);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return pass;
}

function shouldHaveScore(a) {
  var pass = false;
  try {
    pass |= SIZE_REG.test(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0]);
  } catch (ex) {}
  if (!pass) console.log(a);
  return pass;
}

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function getAuthorId(a) {
  return a.owner.user_id;
}

function process() {
  answers = answers.filter(shouldHaveScore)
                   .filter(shouldHaveHeading);
  answers.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = +(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0],
        bB = +(b.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0];
    return aB - bB
  });

  var users = {};
  answers.forEach(function (a) {
    var headline = a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];
    var question = QUESTION_IDs.indexOf(a.question_id);
    var size = parseInt((headline.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0]);
    var language = headline.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];
    var user = getAuthorName(a);
    var userId = getAuthorId(a);
    if (!users[userId]) users[userId] = {name: user, nAnswer: 0, answers: []};
    if (!users[userId].answers[question]) {
      users[userId].answers[question] = {size: Infinity};
      users[userId].nAnswer++;
    }
    if (users[userId].answers[question].size > size) {
      users[userId].answers[question] = {size: size, link: a.share_link}
    }
  });
  
  
  var sortedUsers = [];
  for (var userId in users)
    if (users.hasOwnProperty(userId)) {
      var user = users[userId];
      user.score = 0;
      user.completedAll = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < QUESTION_IDs.length; ++i) {
        if (user.answers[i])
          user.score += user.answers[i].size;
        else
          user.completedAll = false;
      }
      sortedUsers.push(user);
    }  
  
  sortedUsers.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.nAnswer > b.nAnswer) return -1;
    if (b.nAnswer > a.nAnswer) return 1;
    return a.score - b.score;
  });
  
  var place = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedUsers.length; ++i) {
    var user = sortedUsers[i];
    var row = '<tr><td>'+ place++ +'.</td><td>'+user.name+'</td>';
    for (var j = 0; j < QUESTION_IDs.length; ++j) {
      var answer = user.answers[j];
      if (answer)
        row += '<td><a href="'+answer.link+'">'+answer.size+'</a></td>';
      else
        row += '<td class="missing"></td>';
    }
    row += '<td></td>';
    if (user.completedAll)
      row += '<td class="total">'+user.score+'</td>';
    else
      row += '<td class="total missing">'+user.score+'</td>';
    row += '</tr>';
    $("#users").append(row);
  }
}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#leaderboard {
  width: 500px; 
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

td.total {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

td.missing {
  background: #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="leaderboard">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <p>
    Missing scores are shown as grey cells. A grey total indicates that the user has not participated in all challenges and is not eligible for the overall victory yet.
  </p>
  <table class="_user-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>User</td>
        <td><a href="http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66068">#1</a></td>
        <td></td><td>Total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="users">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are the initial numbers positive integers?

Comment: "*both `a` or `b`*"—well, which one? Both, or either one?

Comment: @Doorknob -_- Its both.

Comment: @xnor no. Look at the last test-case.

Comment: Making this part of a series causes a kind of unfortunate situation. This is so simple that solutions are all going to look quite similar. And posting similar solutions in languages that were already used is generally frowned upon. I wrote my solution in about 2 minutes, but it's in a language that was already used, and it's the same length. If I follow typical posting etiquette, I won't be able to participate in the series.

Comment: the leaderboard snippet seems to be incorrectly reporting Eumel's score.

Comment: @JohnE I've edited the answer to get it reported as "21", but I don't think think it should be compared with the byte counts of the other answers in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

### CJam, 16 bytes

```
{{_2$+2/@@*mq}*}
```

Takes input on the stack as `a b n` where `a` and `b` are doubles. [Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1%202dmq%2010%0A%0A%7B%7B_2%24%2B2%2F%40%40*mq%7D*%7D%0A%0A~%5D%60)

Answer (score 9):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 15 bytes

```
.5∘(+.×,×.*⍨)⍣⎕
```

Takes (*a*,*b*) as right argument, and prompts for *n*:

`(`

`+.×` dot product of 0.5 and the right argument

`,` followed by

`×.*⍨` "dot power" of the right argument and 0.5<sup>*</sup>

`)⍣⎕` applied numeric-prompt times.

<sup>*</sup> "dot power" is like dot product, but using multiplication and power instead of plus and multiplication, as follows:

<sub>*n*</sub>
`A ×.*⍨ B` is **∏** *B<sub>i</sub><sup>A</sup>* = **∏** *B*<sub>1</sub>*<sup>A</sup>B*<sub>2</sub><sup>*A*</sup>
      <sup>*i*=1</sup>

-3 bytes thanks to ngn.

---

Old version:

```
{((+/÷≢),.5*⍨×/)⍣⍺⊢⍵}
```

Takes `n` as left argument and `a b` as right argument.

`⊢⍵` On the RightArg
`(`...`)⍣⍺` recalculate LeftArg times
`(+/÷≢)` sum divided by tally
`,` followed by
`.5*⍨×/` the square root of the product.

All the test cases:

```
      f←{((.5×+/),.5*⍨×/)⍣⍺⊢⍵}
      0 1 2 5 10 10 f¨ (24 6)(24 6)(24 6)(24 6)(100 50)(1,2*.5)
┌────┬─────┬────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│24 6│15 12│13.5 13.41640786│13.45817148 13.45817148│72.83955155 72.83955155│1.198140235 1.198140235│
└────┴─────┴────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Is `f⍣⍺⊢⍵` or similar an idiom you use professionally?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yes, see e.g. `Of⍣core⊢TREE` at [miserver.dyalog.com](http://miserver.dyalog.com/) (click the big "D" and scroll to line [266]).

Answer (score 7):

### TI-BASIC, 22 bytes

```
Input N
For(I,1,N
{mean(Ans),√(prod(Ans
End
Ans
```

Does exactly what the algorithm says. Takes N from the prompt, and A and B through `Ans` as a two-element list.

If N is 0, the `For(` loop is skipped entirely.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES7, <s>48</s> 43 bytes

-5 thanks to Downgoat!

```
f=(n,a,b)=>n?f(n-1,(a+b)/2,(a*b)**.5):[a,b]
```

Very simple recursive function.

Comment: `(a*b)**.5` is shorter than `Math.sqrt(a*b)`. [example](http://server.vihan.ml/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3D(n%2Ca%2Cb)%3D%3En%3Ff(n-1%2C(a%2Bb)%2F2%2C(a*b)**.5)%3A%5Ba%2Cb%5D%0Af(1%2C%2024%2C%206))

Comment: @Downgoat That's ES7, but meh.

Answer (score 6):

## MATLAB/Octave, <s>69</s> 65 bytes

```
function [a,b]=r(a,b,n)
for i=1:n;j=(a+b)/2;b=(a*b)^.5;a=j;end
```

Comment: You could do `b=(a*b).^5` directly as you are not reusing `b` again in that iteration and save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
SH;P½¥ðṛ¡
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=U0g7UMK9wqXDsOG5m8Kh&input=&args=WzI0LjAsIDYuMF0+NQ)

#### How it works

```
SH;P½¥ðṛ¡    Input: x (vector) -- y (repetitions)

SH           Take the sum (S) of x and halve (H) the result.
   P½        Take the product (P) of x and the square root (½) of the result.
     ¥       Combine the last two instructions in a dyadic chain.
  ;          Concatenate the results to the left and to the right.
      ð      Push the preceding, variadic chain; begin a new, dyadic chain.
       ṛ     Return the right argument (y).
        ¡    Repeat the pushed chain y times.
```

Answer (score 5):

### C++, <s>108</s> <s>102</s> 100 bytes

Thank you to @RetoKoradi and @AlexA for saving me 6 bytes.

This is non-competitive, because C++ is not a good golfing language. Did this for fun :)

```
#include<cmath>
std::string f(float a,float b,int n){return n==0?a+" "+b:f((a+b)/2,sqrt(a*b),n-1);}
```

This is a simple recursion function, very similar to the JS answer.

Comment: You can get rid of the spaces after the commas. Also, using `float` instead of `double` is shorter.

Comment: You can also remove the space in the `#include` line.

Comment: Wow, I'm stupid not to notice that. Thanks!

Comment: I would consider `f(float*s)` which takes a pointer to 3 floats to be in a "reasonable format". Not sure if that actually makes it shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## K5, 15 bytes

Very literal:

```
{(+/x%2;%*/x)}/
```

In action:

```
 {(+/x%2;%*/x)}/[0; 24 6]
24 6
 {(+/x%2;%*/x)}/[5; 24 6]
1.345817e1 1.345817e1
```

Unfortunately, this does not work in oK because that interpreter does not currently support projection (currying) of adverbs. Works in the real k5.

In oK, it would currently be necessary to wrap the definition in a lambda:

```
  {x{(+/x%2;%*/x)}/y}[5; 24 6]
13.4582 13.4582
```

Answer (score 4):

## J,  <s>18</s> 13 bytes

```
-:@+/,%:@*/^:
```

Usage:

```
   agm =: -:@+/,%:@*/^:
   5 agm 24 6
13.4582 13.4582
```

Comment: Wow, this works. Conjunctions are weird. I would expect this expression to be an adverb (which it can be), but if presented with arguments it is also a function.

Answer (score 4):

### Seriously, 11 bytes

```
,p`;π√@æk`n
```

Hex Dump:

```
2c70603be3fb40916b606e
```

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c70603be3fb40916b606e&input=[3,24,6])

Explanation:

```
,                    Read in the list as [n,a,b]
 p                   pop list to yield: n [a,b]
  `      `n          Push a quoted function and run it n times.
   ;                 Duplicate [a,b] pair
    π√               Compute its product and square root it (GM)
      @              Swap the other copy of the pair to the top
       æ             Compute its mean.
        k            Compile the stack back into a list.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 24 bytes <s>25 33</s>

*Saved 9 <s>7</s> bytes thank to @ETHproductions*

```
Uo r@[VW]=[V+W /2(V*W q]
```

Takes advantage of ES6 destructuring.

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VW8gckBbVlddPVtWK1cgLzIoVipXIHFd&input=MTAgMTAwIDUw)

#### Ungolfed && Explanation

```
Uo r@[VW]=[V+W /2(V*W q]

       // Implicit: U: 1st input, V: 2nd input, W: 3rd input
Uo     // Range from 0 to 1st input
r@     // Loop over range
  [V,W]=    // Set 2nd and 3rd input to...
   [V+W /2,   // Add 2nd and 3rd inputs, divide by 2
   (V*W q]    // Multiple 2nd and 3rd inputs, find square root
            // Set's to the above respectively 
       // Implicit: return [V,W]
```

Comment: `Uo` generates a range of numbers from 0 to U, so `Uo m@[V,W]=[V+W /2,(V*W q]` should work. (Untested)

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't need the commas at all. :)

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks yet again! :)

Comment: Oh dear, this fails for any `U` other than 1, outputting each loop as it goes. Here's one that works properly: `Uo £[VW]=[V+W /2(V*W q]};[VW]`

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks, but using `r` seemed to work also

Comment: Ah, `r` works much better; nice job outsmarting me in my own language. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 12

```
u,.OG@*FG2EQ
```

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2C.OG%40%2AFG2EQ&input=%5B1%2C%201.41421356237%5D%0A10&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B24%2C%206%5D%0A0%20%20%20%0A%5B24%2C%206%5D%0A1%0A%5B24%2C%206%5D%0A2%0A%5B24%2C%206%5D%0A5%0A%5B100%2C%2050%5D%0A10%0A%5B1%2C%201.41421356237%5D%0A10&debug=0&input_size=2)

#### Explanation

```
u,.OG@*FG2EQ    ##  implicit: Q = eval(input())
u         EQ    ##  reduce eval(input()) times, starting with Q
                ##  the reduce lambda has G as the previous value and H as the next
  .OG           ##  arithmetic mean of last pair
     @*FG2      ##  geometric mean of last pair, uses *F to get the product of the list
                ##  and @...2 to get the square root of that
 ,              ##  join the two means into a two element list
```

Comment: Forgot about `@` and `.O`, but I didn't even know the new purpose of `E`.

Comment: @orlp ah, didn't see your post, my bad I would have just suggested these in the comments. And yeah, keeping track of all the changing stuff is a bit of a struggle :P

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 54 bytes

```
function x=f(x,n)
for k=1:n
x=[mean(x) prod(x)^.5];end
```

Example:

```
>> f([24 6], 2)
ans =
  13.500000000000000  13.416407864998739
```

Answer (score 2):

## Minkolang v0.14, 23 bytes

Try it [here](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24n[%24d%2B2%24%3Ar*1Mi2%25%3F!r]%24N.&input=24%206%202)!

```
$n[$d+2$:r*1Mi2%?!r]$N.
$n                      C get all input C
  [                ]    C pop N; repeat inner N times C
   $d                   C duplicate stack [1,2] => [1,2,1,2] C
     +                  C add top two elements C
      2$:               C divide by two C
         r              C reverse stack (get the other two) C
          *             C multiply them together C
           1M           C take square root C
             i2%?!r     C reverse the stack if an odd step number C
                    $N  C output stack
           1M           C take square root C
             i          C get step in for loop C
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>65</s> 55 bytes

Thanks to mathmandan for pointing out a shorter version using the `lambda` operator.

```
f=lambda a,b,n:f((a+b)/2,(a*b)**.5,n-1)if n else(a,b)
```

### My original version:

```
def f(a,b,n):
 if n:f((a+b)/2,(a*b)**.5,n-1)
 else:print(a,b)
```

To my chagrin, a recursive function (a la the JavaScript and C++ answers) was shorter than a simple for loop.

Comment: You can shorten this a little with `lambda` and the ternary `if/else` operator: `f=lambda a,b,n:f((a+b)/2,(a*b)**.5,n-1)if n else(a,b)`

Comment: No problem!  (Also, I think this is 53 bytes.)

Comment: The .py file I have saved is listed as being 55 bytes.  Is there a better way to calculate program size?

Comment: Sometimes people on this site copy and paste their code into https://mothereff.in/byte-counter .  If you're wondering about the discrepancy, I would guess that Windows is inserting an unnecessary newline character at the end of your .py file (and Windows counts a newline as 2 bytes instead of 1).  Either way, you don't have to count that last newline as part of your code for scoring purposes. If you do post a multiple-line entry, you should count 1 for each newline character, not 2, and not including any newline at the end of your last line of code. (As far as I understand the rules anyway!)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
u,^*FG.5csG2vzQ
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

Saved one byte thanks to Martin Büttner.

```
{+##/2,(1##)^.5}&@@#&~Nest~##&
```

Usage:

```
In[1]:= {+##/2,(1##)^.5}&@@#&~Nest~##&[{24, 6}, 5]

Out[1]= {13.4582, 13.4582}
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 66 bytes

```
f=function(a,b,n){while(n){x=(a+b)/2;b=(a*b)^.5;n=n-1;a=x};c(a,b)}
```

Usage:

```
> f(24,6,0)
[1] 24  6
> f(24,6,1)
[1] 15 12
> f(24,6,2)
[1] 13.50000 13.41641
> f(24,6,3)
[1] 13.45820 13.45814
> f(24,6,4)
[1] 13.45817 13.45817
> f(100,50,10)
[1] 72.83955 72.83955
> f(1,1.41421356237,10)
[1] 1.19814 1.19814
```

Comment: You can remove the function name to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 62 bytes

```
n,a,b=...for i=1,n do a,b=(a+b)/2,math.sqrt(a*b)end print(a,b)
```

Uses command line arguments from `...` to assign to `n`, `a` and `b`, a nifty trick I learned about Lua recently.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>62</strike> <strike>61</strike> 62 bytes

```
def f(a,b,n):
 while n:a,b=(a+b)/2.,(a*b)**.5;n-=1
 print a,b
```

Comment: The program should only print once, when it terminates.

Comment: My misunderstanding.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 47 Bytes

```
f a b 0=(a,b)
f a b n=f((a+b)/2)(sqrt$a*b)(n-1)
```

Comment: you could save some bytes taking a b as a couple in f:   f x 0=x;f(a,b)n=f((a+b)/2,sqrt$a*b)$n-1

Comment: And define the function infix.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 40 bytes

```haskell
(!!).iterate(\(a,b)->((a+b)/2,sqrt$a*b))
```

An anonymous function. Example usage:

```haskell
>> let f=(!!).iterate(\(a,b)->((a+b)/2,sqrt$a*b)) in f (1.0,1.41421356237) 10
(1.198140234734168,1.1981402347341683)
```

The lambda function `(\(a,b)->((a+b)/2,sqrt$a*b))` takes the arithmetic and geometric mean on a tuple. This is iterated starting with the first input (a tuple), and then `(!!)` indexes the second input to specify the number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 60 bytes

```
perl -ape'F=($F[0]/2+$F[1]/2,sqrt$F[0]*$F[1])for 1..shift@F;$_="@F"'
```

**N.B.:** Per [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), I *believe* I've got the scoring correct. The actual code (between single quotes) is 58 characters, then I added +2 for `a` and `p` flags as that's the difference from the shortest invocation, `perl -e'...'`

#### Vague complaints

I have this nagging feeling I'm missing an obvious improvement. I know, "welcome to code golf", but I mean *more than usual* I believe there's an easy opportunity to shorten this.

Early on, I had messed around with using `$\` as the second term with some success, but the above approach ended up being 2 bytes shorter, even with the extra `ap` flags required. Similarly, avoiding the explicit `$_` assignment would be nice, but the loop makes that difficult.

The `shift@F` bugs me, too; if I don't do it that way, though (or use `@F=(0,...,...)` instead, which doesn't save any bytes), there's an off-by-one error with the `@F` assignment.

#### Example

```
echo 5 24 6 | perl -ape'F=($F[0]/2+$F[1]/2,sqrt$F[0]*$F[1])for 1..shift@F;$_="@F"'
```

#### Outputs

```
13.4581714817256 13.4581714817256
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 49 bytes

```
(a,b,n)->(for i=1:n;a,b=(a+b)/2,√(a*b)end;(a,b))
```

Pretty direct iterative algorithm. Using the`√` symbol and the multiple return saves a few bytes, but the for loop syntax costs a few.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 42 bytes

```julia
f(a,b,n)=n>0?f((a+b)/2,(a*b)^.5,n-1):(a,b)
```

This is a recursive function `f` that accepts three numbers and returns a tuple.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(a::Real, b::Real, n::Integer)
    if n > 0
        # Recurse on the arithmetic and geometric means, decrementing n
        return f((a + b) / 2, sqrt(a * b), n - 1)
    else
        # Return the pair
        return (a, b)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## LabVIEW, 21 LabVIEW Primitives

Primitives counted as per [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490).

[image]

pretty staightforward not much to explain.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 16 bytes

```
{{_:+2/\:*mq]}*}
```

This is an anonymous function. The input is a list with the two values (as doubles), followed by the iteration count. [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%0A%7B%7B_%3A%2B2%2F%5C%3A*mq%5D%7D*%7D%0A~%60&input=%5B24.0%206.0%5D%202) with I/O code for testing.

I wouldn't normally have posted this because @PeterTaylor posted an equally long CJam answer before I saw the question. But since this is advertised as the start of a series, I wanted to keep my options open in case the series is interesting.

While the length is the same as Peter's answer, the code is not. I chose a different input format by taking the two values in a list, where Peter used separate values. So while there's not much to it with either input format, the code looks quite different.

```
{     Start loop over number of iterations.
  _     Copy the current pair of values.
  :+    Reduce pair with + operator.
  2/    Divide by 2.
  \     Swap second copy of pair to top.
  :*    Reduce pair with * operator.
  mq    Calculate square root.
  ]     Wrap the two new values in a list for next iteration.
}*    End iteration loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 66 bytes

Uses newtons method to approximate the square root in 15 steps

```
iii>:?v~naon;
*&f:?v\1-@:&$:@$:@+2,@
$@:$@//,2+,@:
4{~$~/\@@1-21.0
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaWlpPjo/dn5uYW9uO1xuKiZmOj92XFwxLUA6JiQ6QCQ6QCsyLEBcbiRAOiRALy8sMissQDpcbjR7fiR+L1xcQEAxLTIxLjAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjEwMCA1MCAxMCIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMifQ==)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 58 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHPa4MwFMfv/hWP0kOyZc5Y7UBQKOziYewwdioenpq0Dhc3kw2K9G93qbYdrJ2B5MH7ft7P6AJr7Jv8TRQG0lI0SkDnfGMNMgKSKsPgsfnKa3GyFOIEXkxbqQ3E0BPFkOU0TipJVOJR@95xRvA2p/c@e0KzdfVnawje5JSKWgvQszmyeT7rAUoh4R0rRbDd6AhWbYu79Zg7oxG8qsrYGp0D9hxaMkKbArXQ1jvAZJDgGLlSu4x4DPygZLAsKbtU@aTqT6rhdGZbmHue1UPvf8DK3A144PNFuPQXDyUdQOoM5jyfK5tWYLGF7uyzaz/m/LD7MbUi8jT9byDxqIs6VdqgKsSzXNsPzNglxv9g49deI/3r5BGkY/t753D3/Q8)

```scala
(n,a,b)=>if(n>0)f(n-1,(a+b)/2,Math.sqrt(a*b))else s"$a,$b"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
{[m;pƭ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSU1QjI0JTNCNiU1RCUyMDUmY29kZT0lN0IlNUJtJTNCcCVDNiVBRCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSZmbGFncz0=)

Takes input [on the stack](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22106/114446). This default was [+11/-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu1bk.png) at the time of posting ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605031557/https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?page=3&tab=scoredesc)).

##### Explanation

```python
{[m;pƭ  # Implicit input
{       # First input no. times:
 [ ;    #  Parallelly apply:
  m     #   Arithmetic mean
    pƭ  #   Square root of product
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>95</s> 92 bytes

```go
import(."math";."fmt")
func f(n,a,b float64){for;n>0.;n--{a,b=(a+b)/2,Sqrt(a*b)}
Print(a,b)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDRSsMwFIbv8xQhUEj0NKZdW8XSPYPg5TYkLWYW17R26VXok3hTBO98IW99Es-2Olkg5D855Hz_n_ePbTt9dbp61dtn2ujafg7OhHff67rp2t5xyRrtXlgumWkcE8QMtqKGW9BQUrNrtcsS4U3b53apZG7D0GOn4Pq6FDcxPL7hDH1VipE89LVFDahnxs9x2AHKBfWktt3g9vS-oKvN3vVD5fwFZvTEK4gTyEYgPjqr-KzS_66CSClI1V8BkUyiJI4WaRYvbvF2JARd0ydwB2KvLeafHfiTV8NZIJWhq8BAYDa0WK4txcWAOmnBSY27xC_hF-Xx7Q4jIWJOOk2n8xc)

Prints to STDOUT, with a space separating the means.

The explicitly looped solution is the same length as the recursive solution, funnily enough (all byte savings from making it recursive is lost by needing an extra `else{}` block to prevent output when `n>0`).

- -3 by @The Thonnu

Comment: [92 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDRSsMwFIbv8xQhUEj0NKZdW8XSPYPg5TYkLWYW17R26VXok3hTBO98IW99Es-2Olkg5D855Hz_n_ePbTt9dbp61dtn2ujafg7OhHff67rp2t5xyRrtXlgumWkcE8QMtqKGW9BQUrNrtcsS4U3b53apZG7D0GOn4Pq6FDcxPL7hDH1VipE89LVFDahnxs9x2AHKBfWktt3g9vS-oKvN3vVD5fwFZvTEK4gTyEYgPjqr-KzS_66CSClI1V8BkUyiJI4WaRYvbvF2JARd0ydwB2KvLeafHfiTV8NZIJWhq8BAYDa0WK4txcWAOmnBSY27xC_hF-Xx7Q4jIWJOOk2n8xc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>53</s>  47 bytes

```perl6
{(($^a,$^b),->(\a,\b){((a+b)/2,sqrt(a*b))}...*)[$^n]} # 53 bytes
```

usage:

```perl6
# give it a name
my &code = {(($^a,$^b),->(\a,\b){((a+b)/2,sqrt(a*b))}...*)[$^n]}

say code 100,50,10;          # (72.8395515523453 72.8395515523453)
say code 1,1.41421356237,10; # (1.19814023473417 1.19814023473417)
```

---

If I change the input from `a,b,n` to `(a,b),n` I can save a few bytes.

```perl6
{($^l,->(\a,\b){((a+b)/2,sqrt(a*b))}...*)[$^n]} # 47 bytes
```

usage:

```perl6
my &code = {($^l,->(\a,\b){((a+b)/2,sqrt(a*b))}...*)[$^n]}

say code (100,50),10;          # (72.8395515523453 72.8395515523453)
say code (1,1.41421356237),10; # (1.19814023473417 1.19814023473417)

say code (24,6),$_ for 0,1,2,5;
# (24 6)
# (15 12)
# (13.5 13.4164078649987)
# (13.4581714817256 13.4581714817256)
```

```perl6
{
  (
    $^l,          # first 2 element tuple
    ->            # pointy block (lambda)
      (\a,\b)     # take a single tuple, and give its 2 elements each a name
    {
      (           # create a 2 element tuple
        (a+b)/2,  # arithmetic mean
        sqrt(a*b) # geometric mean
      )
    } ... *       # create a lazy infinite sequence of tuples
  )[ $^n ]        # take the nth "tuple" from the outer sequence
}
```

---

Really I would swap out the `... *` with `... -> (\a,\b) { a =~= b }`, then there would be no need for the `$^n` parameter.
( do not use `==` instead of `=~=`, or it may not stop )

```perl6
my &code = {($^l,->(\a,\b){((a+b)/2,sqrt(a*b))}...->(\a,\b){a=~=b})[*-1]}

say code (24,6);           # (13.4581714817256 13.4581714817256)
say code (100,50);         # (72.8395515523453 72.8395515523453)
say code (1,1.41421356237) # (1.19814023473417 1.19814023473417)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog, 80 bytes

**Code:**

```
p(A,B,0):-write([A,B]).
p(A,B,N):-X is(A+B)/2,Y is sqrt(A*B),M is N-1,p(X,Y,M).
```

**Example:**

```
p(100,50,10).
[72.83955155234534, 72.83955155234534]
```

Try it online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/eYhaEPoG.pl)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>103</s> <s>96</s> 84 bytes

```java
String f(int n,double a,double b){return n>0?f(n-1,(a+b)/2,Math.sqrt(a*b)):a+","+b;}
```

[Verify all testcases.](http://ideone.com/BY4OuV)

Old version (96 bytes):

```java
String f(int n,double a,double b){for(;n>0;a=(a+b)/2,b=Math.sqrt((b-2*a)*b))n--;return a+","+b;}
```

Old version (103 bytes):

```java
String f(int n,double a,double b){double t;for(;n>0;t=(a+b)/2,b=Math.sqrt(a*b),a=t)n--;return a+","+b;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
(₌ṁΠ√W
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCIo4oKM4bmBzqDiiJpXIiwiIiwiNVxuWzI0LCA2XSJd)

The obvious 6 byte solution

### Explained

```
(₌ṁΠ√W­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
(       # ‎⁡n times:
 ₌ṁ     # ‎⁢  Push the mean of the top of the stack
 ₌ Π    # ‎⁣  And the product of the top of the stack
    √   # ‎⁤  Square root that product
     W  # ‎⁢⁡  And wrap into a list
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).